# How to avoid repetition of job in celery

Tags: celery, scheduled-tasks, amazon-sqs, repeat

I am using celery with SQS.
One of my celery worker go to DB and check for pending messages and sends notification.
I have 2 worker doing same job.
The problem here is this job is scheduled and there are 2 worker for job so this causing a problem that some of the messages are getting sent twice.
How to avoid 2 jobs picking same message?
Should I stop using 2 worker for processing scheduled jobs?

Comment: Are you using a timezone other than UTC?

Comment: @2ps I am using UTC only